# How to upload file from external URL into posts programmatically

Tags: wordpress, sap-data-services

I've custom content type, added by BODS, and I've added a file field, that should save a PDF file from external URL.

How to save it programmatically?

I know how to save the image but it seems that for the PDF files it's a different approach.